# Prevent concurrent update on Postgresql database row

Tags: php, postgresql, concurrency

I have a query like below to increase count of transaction after each transaction happening through a specific gateway. The below query is used in a PHP application which does post transaction maintenance jobs. How to make sure two concurrent updates do not create a trouble in the count?

Thinking of using advisory locks of PostgreSQL, but not sure how to use it in below context. Have few references in Java but is relatively new in PHP.

Query 1 (To find the record to be updated):

```
SELECT id
FROM Client.gatewaystat_tbl
WHERE clientid = 1 AND gatewayid = 2 ;
```

If record found:

```
UPDATE gatewaystat_tbl gt
SET statvalue = statvalue + 1
WHERE id = '<from above query>'
```

If record not found:

```
INSERT INTO client.gatewaystat_tbl
   (gatewayid, clientid, statetypeid, statvalue)
VALUES (2, 1, 1, 1);
```

The above code may be called multiple time within a second, as transactions will happen at a very high volume during peak hours and after every transaction the counter (`statvalue`) needs to be increased. How to make sure that multiple threads do not try to update the count at the same time and end up with erroneous data?

Answer (score 0):

No update to `statvalue` can get lost, because the `UPDATE` is atomic. The row will get locked before the statement, and the lock will only be released when the transaction commits.

But while you cannot lose an update to `statvalue`, other problems can happen:

1. A concurrent transaction could update or delete the row between the `SELECT` and the `UPDATE`.
2. A concurrent transaction could insert a conflicting row between the `SELECT` and the `INSERT`.

You can protect yourself against the first problem by using `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` which will lock the row, but you have to be ready to handle errors during the `INSERT`.

If you have a primary key or unique constraint on `(gatewayid, clientid)`, you could do it all in a single statement and avoid all these problems:

```
INSERT INTO client.gatewaystat_tbl
   (gatewayid, clientid, statetypeid, statvalue)
VALUES (2, 1, 1, 1)
ON CONFLICT (gatewayid, clientid) DO UPDATE
   SET statvalue = statvalue + 1;
```

Comment: Will the single statement be atomic too ?  It would first attempt to insert and on conflict would update. What is the overheard, as the insert will happen only once a month as will reset (disable the row for previous month by setting "enable" column value as 'false')on every months's 1st day.

Comment: I would believe that the overhead is not terrible (an update is pretty similar to an insert), but you should benchmark it to be sure.

Comment: This feature is available only above Postgres 9.5 above. We are using Postgres 9.3 and 9.4 is some environments.

Comment: Then you cannot use it and have to deal with the potential race condition by handling errors during `INSERT` and `UPDATE`s that change no row. Or you upgrade - 9.3 will go out of support this fall.